# Printing php values in the HTML

Tags: php, html

I am querying my database and getting the values to I need to print on my webpage.

```
          <div class="col-6 col-middle"> <span class="h4"> <a href="#" class="text-normal">**A**</a> </span>
            <div class="actions row-space-top-1"> <a href="#">**B**</a> </div>
            <div class="actions row-space-top-1"> <b>Duration:</b>**C**</div>
            <div class="actions row-space-top-1"> <b>Travel date:</b>**D**</div>
          </div>
```

Now where I have mentioned A,B,C,D I need to print my php values...

```
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "Name :{$row['A']}  <br> ".
                 "Date_Of_Travel : {$row['B']} <br> ".
                 "No_Of_Days : {$row['C']} <br> ";

        }
```

Also I need to loop the HTML for the number rows that I have.

The output should look like
[image]

Kindly guide.

Comment: So you're looking for a template framework / library ? Such behavior is not native in PHP.

Comment: Try echoing the data as some sort of html object and style that object with css.

Comment: Nothing like framework / library. Some normal logic that can make it work ?

Comment: What about print screen button on keyboard? Btw i can see some floresan light top of your room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>
      <div class="col-6 col-middle"> <span class="h4"> <a href="#" class="text-normal"><?php echo $result['a'] ?></a></span>
       <div class="actions row-space-top-1"> <a href="#"><?php echo $result['B'] ?></a> </div>
        <div class="actions row-space-top-1"> <b>Duration:</b><?php echo $result['C'] ?></div>
        <div class="actions row-space-top-1"> <b>Travel date:</b><?php echo $result[D'] ?></div>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: what are you getting back?? Any Errors?

Comment: if i do echo "abc"; i can see abc .. but when I do <?php echo $result['D'] .. i cant see the value of D

Comment: There wouldn't be any data in the database. Maybe?

Comment: the problem was with using <? instead of <?php .. as in php.ini is was not On